# Non-surjectivity of exponential map: how to understand?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I'm given to understand the exponential map is not generally surjective -- the standard example is $\mathrm{SL}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ [[ 1 ]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/643216/non-surjectivity-of-the-exponential-map-to-sl2-mathbbc).

I can clearly see why this is so in the non-connected case -- the tangent space is a tangent space to the connected component alone, so its image must be contained in the connected component. **I do not see why the map isn't surjective in the connected case.**

I also don't see why the map is then *again* surjective in the compact case -- [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_torus#Properties) claims that this is a special case of "the exponential map is surjective if every element is contained in a maximal torus". Is this right? Is there a good way to understand why this is true?

---

Note that I am not looking for counter-examples: I'm aware of them. I'm looking for intuition -- perhaps a clever look at what the image of the exponential map actually looks like in the non-surjective case (how it "misses" some of the points in the group).

As an analogy, if asked to explain smooth non-analytic functions, it would be more instructive (than simply providing the example of $e^{-1/x}$) to explain that a function may grow slower than all polynomials near zero -- and provide the construction as $1/f(1/x)$ from any function $f$ that grows faster than all polynomials as $x\to\infty$.

(See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3368390/developing-intuition-for-lie-groups-and-lie-algebras) for more examples of the kind of intuition I'm looking for, within the context of Lie theory.)

Comment: The exponential map is surjective around $1$ but its image is not a subgroup. For $GL(n,\Bbb{R})$ one frontier is the radius of convergence of $\log(I+.)$ and its image under conjugaison. It is surjective iff every element is $=\exp(A)$ thus contained in a torus $\exp(tA)$

Comment: There's a standard proof for the compact case. In summary: (1) Since $G$ is compact, it admits a bi-invariant metric. (2) For a bi-invariant metric the (Lie algebra) exponential and the (geodesic) exponential maps coincide. (3) Apply the Hopf-Rinow Theorem. https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/06/25/two-small-facts-about-lie-groups/